# A non-differentiable function $f(x,y)$ with bounded $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Recently I was trying to construct a counterexample to the statement "If there exist $f_{xy}(0,0)$, $f_{yx}(0,0)$ and the functions $f_{xx}$, $f_{yy}$ exist in some neighborhood and are continuous at $(0,0)$, then $f$ is twice differentiable at $(0,0)$". In order to do that the following question arose:

Is there a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with bounded $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_{xx}$, $f_{yy}$, which is non-differentiable at $(0,0)$?

If there exists such a function, then we're done. The functions which came to mind have unbounded second partials $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$.

Comment: This function will be locally bounded with bounded (distributional) Laplacian which will give $C^1$ regularity (in fact $C^{1,1-\varepsilon}$), by Schauder estimates.

Comment: Thanks, Professor Tao! Now I see that the initial statement which I tried to disproof is in fact correct: $f_x,f_y\in D(0,0)$ due to sufficient condition and thus bounded in $O_\delta(0,0)$. So $f\in W^1_\infty(O_\delta(0,0))$ and $\Delta f\in L_\infty(O_\delta(0,0))$, which means $f\in W^2_\infty(O_\delta(0,0))\subset C^{1,1-\varepsilon}(O_\delta(0,0))$ by Schauder estimates and thus $f\in D^2(0,0)$! If there is some kind of Schauder estimate by other bounded pairs: $f_{xx},f_{yx}$ or $f_{xy},f_{yx}$ or $f_{xy},f_{yy}$, I think it will be a new sufficient condition of twice differentiability!