# A sufficient condition for multiple differentiability of a function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

While working on some properties of partial derivatives and multiply differentiable functions of several variables, I came across the following Hypothesis 1:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, $\delta>0$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and for each partial derivative $D^{k-1}f:=\partial_{i_1}\ldots\partial_{i_{k-1}}f$ of $f$ of order $k-1$ one of its partials $\partial_1D^{k-1}f,\ldots,\partial_nD^{k-1}f$ exists at $\mathbb{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and that the remaining $n-1$ of them exist in some neighborhood $O_\delta(\mathbb{a})$ and are continuous at $\mathbb{a}$. Then $f$ is $k$ times differentiable at $\mathbb{a}$ (i.e. $f$ is $k-1$ times differentiable in some neighborhood of $\mathbb{a}$ and all of its partials of order $k-1$ are differentiable at $\mathbb{a}$).

For $k=1$ the statement is true and can be found, for example, in T.Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis" (Th. 12.11). I wonder if anyone saw this statement somewhere for $k\geqslant 2$ or has any suggestions on its proof (or maybe a counterexample for disproof)?

First I started with the case $n=k=2$ and tried to find a counterexample (similar to one constructed in https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/8/11/1946/htm), namely I tried to construct a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f_{xy}$ , $f_{yx}$ exist at $(0,0)$ and $f_{xx}$, $f_{yy}$ exist in some neighborhood and are continuous at $(0,0)$, but $f$ is $\textit{not}$ twice differentiable at $(0,0)$ (i.e. there is no neighborhood of $(0,0)$ where $f$ is differentiable, because the defferentiability of $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(0,0)$ follows from the Apostol's case $k=1$). But [T.Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao) pointed out that in this setting $f$ belongs to $C^1$ in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$ by Shauder estimates (see [A non-differentiable function $f(x,y)$ with bounded $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397850/a-non-differentiable-function-fx-y-with-bounded-f-x-f-y-f-xx-and)), so $f$ is in fact $\textit{twice differentiable}$ at $(0,0)$! Now it seems to me that Hypothesis 1 is in fact true! In order to prove it in case $n=k=2$ there are two cases remaining: assume that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are differentiable at $\mathbb{a}$ and either

1. $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist in some neighborhood and are continuous at $(0,0)$,
   or
2. $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist in $O_\delta(\mathbb{a})$ exist in some neighborhood and are continuous at $(0,0)$.

Prove that $f$ is differentiable in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Shauder estimates don't work in these cases. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear: why do you call $D^{k-1}f$ a "partial derivative"? In Hypothesis $1$ you are already assuming $f$ is $k-1$ differentiable in a nbd of $a$, don't you? Then the conclusion would follow by the usual Total Differential Theorem applied to the map $x\mapsto D^{k-1}f(x)$ (and less is needed)

Comment: No, I don't assume it, that's the point! By $D^{k-1}f:=\partial_{i_1}\ldots\partial_{i_{k-1}}f$ I simply denote a partial derivative of order $k-1$, not a total differential of order $k-1$! Maybe I should edit and make it more clear...

Comment: Ok, thank you! And all the partial derivatives of all orders strictly less than k do exist in a nbd of $a$, right?

Comment: Sure, all of the partials of order $k-1$ do exist in $O_\delta(\mathbb{a})$, because for each of them at least one of its first partials exists in $O_\delta(\mathbb{a})$.